# Can I schedule a retry of a cloud function in nodejs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

When subscribing to a topic, I handle the ack/nack myself and can easily call message.nack(millisecondsToNextRetry).

I would like to do the same thing in cloud functions using nodejs, i.e. under certain circumstances retry the function after a specified time.

Anyone know a good solution or workaround when triggering a cloud function from pub/sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the workaround I've been using is Cloud Tasks, scheduling an invocation of the function at a specified time with the Pubsub payload. So I will ack the function and schedule a "retry" with Cloud Tasks at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions will [retry automatically](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) if you [enable that by configuration](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#enabling_and_disabling_retries).  Retries will happen if your function throws an exception, returns a rejected promise, or times out.  You won't be able to control the schedule of retries.